# Vector of tuples of same indexed-elements; determine whether vectors are of same size

Tags: c++, vector, variadic-functions

I am looking to create a vector that stores a tuple of the same-index elements from different vectors.
Although I am able to achieve it, there's a caveat if the caller passes in vectors of different sizes and I am wondering if there's a way to determine whether all passed in vectors are of the same size.

```
template <typename... Args>
std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>> Foo(const std::vector<Args>&... vecs) 
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<Args...>> result;

    const auto elems = sizeof...(vecs);
    std::cout << "Elems = " << elems << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < elems; ++i) 
    {
        result.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(vecs[i]...));
    }

    return result;
}

vector<int> v1 = {1, 4, 8};
vector<double> v2 = {1.1, 4.1, 8.1};
auto vec1 = Foo(v1, v2); // { {1, 1.1}, {4, 4.1}, {8, 8.1} }
```

Comment: Are you trying to know this at compile time? if yes, it is not possible

Comment: Perhaps it'd only make sense to iterate over `auto elems = std::min({ vecs.size()... });`  elements then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown code doesn't work as expected anyway. `sizeof...` gives you the number of arguments in the pack, not the size of the individual elements of the pack.

Maybe something like this (assuming C++17 or later):

```
template <typename Arg1, typename... Args>
std::vector<std::tuple<Arg1, Args...>> Foo(const std::vector<Arg1>& vec1, const std::vector<Args>&... vecs) 
{
    if(((vec1.size() != vecs.size()) || ...))
        throw std::invalid_argument("All arguments to Foo must have equal length.");

    std::vector<std::tuple<Arg1, Args...>> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i) 
    {
        // emplace_back is pointless if you use don't pass
        // the constructor arguments directly
        // Also make_tuple doesn't always produce tuple<Args...>.
        result.emplace_back(vec1[i], vecs[i]...);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I would consider whether you really need to limit this function to `std::vector` specifically. You could accept any ranges and determine the tuple type from `std::range_value_t` in C++20 or accept iterator pairs and determine the tuple type from dereferencing the iterator.

You can also consider whether it wouldn't make sense to make the function perfectly-forwarding.

If you want to allow an empty argument list, then there is ambiguity in how large the resulting vector ought to be. In that case I would suggest adding a specific overload handling it.

Comment: 1) I see you changed the header which will no longer work with the way I called `Foo`. 2) Possible to provide another solution using ranges? I am new to it

Comment: Why do you say it won't work with how you called foo?

Comment: @MKD 1) Sorry, I forgot to adjust the types everywhere. It should be correct now. 2) Maybe later when I have time.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I assume you intended to @ the other user?

Comment: yep, sorry @MKD see my comment above

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Wo34esE7M

Comment: @MKD I forgot another place... Compiles now.